# Не выводится содержание объекта при клонировании

Tags: java

Есть код

```
public class SimpleClone implements Cloneable { //интерфейс для создания клонов 
    @Override                            
    public SimpleClone clone() { // обработка исключения ошибки клонирования 
        try {
            return (SimpleClone)super.clone();
        }
        catch( CloneNotSupportedException ex ) {
            throw new InternalError();
        }
    }

    public SimpleClone(){  //конструктор класса
        System.out.println("New SimpleClone");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleClone s1 = new SimpleClone( );
        SimpleClone s2 = s1.clone();
    }
}
```

*Output*: `New SimpleClone`

В этом коде я пытаюсь склонировать объект `s1` который выводит некоторую строку.

В моем понимании, *Java* должна мне вывести две строки, а она выводит только первую `s1`.

- Почему она не выводит вторую строку?
- Как при клонировании сделать так чтобы она выводила вторую строку?

Answer (score 6):

- Почему она не выводит вторую строку?

согласно [`Effective Java`](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683)(c. 79):

> **Метод `clone` фактически работает как второй конструктор...**

- Как при клонировании сделать так чтобы она выводила вторую строку?

Ну так а если Вам нужно вызывать код в конструкторе, может тогда стоит просто создать новый объект, а не получать его посредством клонирования...

Так же как вариант возможно создание `конструктора копирования` если важен вызов конструктора.

Comment: Предположим, что clone действительно работает как второй конструктор класса. Что тогда этот  мнимый конструктор принимает на вход?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin да нет никакого мнимого конструктора, Вы же пишите `(SimpleClone)super.clone()` - super классом для что Вашего `SimpleClone` какой класс является? - Правильно, `Object`, а у него уже имеется нативная реализация которая просто берет и копирует содержимое ячеек памяти в другое место а потом уже  получившийся `Object` приводится к `SimpleClone`